# How to have multiple subdomains resolve the same in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the latest Laravel framework and I'm trying to point 2 URLs to the same code base. For instance, I have app.example.com working fine and I want app1.example.com to do the same.

I have all my DNS routing and everything working fine. However, when I reach the public index page using app1.example.com, I get a 404, not the index page as I'm expecting.

I suspect it has something to do w/ my app.php's 'url' value, which is currently set to app.example.com. However, looking through the codebase, I'm not seeing anything in routes that would make me get the 404 based off this URL. Maybe it's because of the magic in the base framework?

I could make the 'url' value variable and just pick up the current URL. I'm not sure if that's truly the problem though or if that would cause other issues down the road.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting a web server 404 or a laravel 404?

Comment: @BlueC laravel 404

Answer (score 1):

I have a method, namely by creating 2 web routes, for example I have 2 routes, namely routes/admin.php, and routes/guest.php, and after that you need to register the two routes in **RouteServiceProvider.php** on function **boot**, as below:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->domain('app1')
        ->as('app1.')
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));

    Route::middleware('web')
        ->domain('app2')
        ->as('app2.')
        ->group(base_path('routes/guest.php'));

    ...
}
```

As you can see above, I added a domain, that's all you need. Your Laravel application now has 2 domains, for each route, adjust it to your needs. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. This directs folks to two different places depending on domain. I'm looking to have them sent to the same places no matter what the domain. I could perhaps put "as()" in both of them and send to the same place, but as "as" is not defined at all in the default RouteServiceProvider, I don't think that would matter. What's your app.php's vue for 'url', or your .env file's value for APP_URL?